# 'numpy.int64' error thwarts my automation of querying Google Distance Matrix API. Solutions?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, numpy, google-maps-api-3, pandas

**Goal:**

To automate obtaining drive duration's by querying a list (see the CSV setup below) of Zipcodes (`'Origin_Zip'`) to Addresses (`'Destination_BH'`) using Google Distance Matrix API to obtain drive time (minutes) in the, `"time_to_BH"` row.  I am using Pandas to move the data between the csv and call Google matrix.  However, I am receiving the following error:

**Error:**

```
TypeError: argument of type 'numpy.int64' is not iterable
```

I am using [this GitHub as blueprint](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python/blob/master/googlemaps/distance_matrix.py) to structure the Google Maps Distance portion. I am using Python 2.7.

**Code:**

```
from google import search
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import googlemaps
from googlemaps import convert
from googlemaps.convert import as_list
import datetime

#stores my API code as 'gmaps'
key = '(my API Key)'
client = googlemaps.Client(key)

#establishes: drive time (in minutes), english, non-metric measurements, trip occurs at 1:00pm PST
def distance_matrix(client, origins, destinations,
                    mode="driving", language="en", avoid=None, units="imperial",
                    departure_time=None, arrival_time=None, transit_mode=None,transit_routing_preference=None):

    #establishes "origin" and "destinations" header format to direct pandas to begin. 
    params = {
    "origins": 'Origin_Zip',
    "destinations": 'Destination_BH'
}

#Reads the strings within csv's("drive_ca.csv") rows via the indicated column (usecols=) to automate queryinig, google distance Matrix API calls 
df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Desktop\drive_ca.csv', usecols=['Origin_Zip'])

#Number  indicates outputs to result
stop = 1

#Assigns a column name to iterate 
urlcols = ['Destination_BH']

# First, apply() to call the google distance Matrix for each 'row'
# A list is built for the urls return by search()
df[urlcols] = df['Origin_Zip'].apply(lambda Origin_Zip : pd.Series([destinations for destinations in search(Origin_Zip, stop=stop, pause=5.0)][:stop]))


departure_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1428580693);

if mode:
    # NOTE(broady): the mode parameter is not validated by the Maps API
    # server. Check here to prevent silent failures.
    if mode not in ["driving", "walking", "bicycling", "transit"]:
        raise ValueError("Invalid travel mode.")
        params["mode"] = mode

    if language:
        params["language"] = language

    if avoid:
        if avoid not in ["tolls", "highways", "ferries"]:
            raise ValueError("Invalid route restriction.")
        params["avoid"] = avoid

    if units:
        params["units"] = units

    if departure_time:
        params["departure_time"] = convert.time(departure_time)

    if arrival_time:
        params["arrival_time"] = convert.time(arrival_time)

    if departure_time and arrival_time:
        raise ValueError("Should not specify both departure_time and"
                         "arrival_time.")

    if transit_mode:
        params["transit_mode"] = convert.join_list("|", transit_mode)

    if transit_routing_preference:
        params["transit_routing_preference"] = transit_routing_preference

    print params

    return client._get("/maps/api/distancematrix/json", params)

#prints corresponding duration to the indicated header row in "drive_ca.csv"
df.to_csv('C:\Users\Desktop\drive_ca.csv', usecols=['Destination_BH'])
```

**Complete Traceback:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-1a75d4fe26fb> in <module>()
     34 # First, apply() to call the google distance Matrix for each 'row'
     35 # A list is built for the urls return by search()
---> 36 df[urlcols] = df['Origin_Zip'].apply(lambda Origin_Zip : pd.Series([destinations for destinations in search(Origin_Zip, stop=stop, pause=5.0)][:stop]))
     37 
     38 

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2056             values = lib.map_infer(values, lib.Timestamp)
   2057 
-> 2058         mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2059         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
   2060             from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\lib.pyd in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:56997)()

<ipython-input-4-1a75d4fe26fb> in <lambda>(Origin_Zip)
     34 # First, apply() to call the google distance Matrix for each 'row'
     35 # A list is built for the urls return by search()
---> 36 df[urlcols] = df['Origin_Zip'].apply(lambda Origin_Zip : pd.Series([destinations for destinations in search(Origin_Zip, stop=stop, pause=5.0)][:stop]))
     37 
     38 

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google.pyc in search(query, tld, lang, num, start, stop, pause, only_standard)
    174 
    175     # Prepare the search string.
--> 176     query = quote_plus(query)
    177 
    178     # Grab the cookie from the home page.

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\urllib.pyc in quote_plus(s, safe)
   1290 def quote_plus(s, safe=''):
   1291     """Quote the query fragment of a URL; replacing ' ' with '+'"""
-> 1292     if ' ' in s:
   1293         s = quote(s, safe + ' ')
   1294         return s.replace(' ', '+')

TypeError: argument of type 'numpy.int64' is not iterable
```

**.CSV Setup:**

[image: CSV I am using to query]

Comment: Where's the error (line number/contents of that line)? Can you include the entire stack trace?

Comment: Just added the traceback in. Apologies for not having that initially. Thanks

Comment: That's quite a long lambda function in your apply, I recommend writing as a function. For one thing it'll be easier to debug (clearer which line is causing the error). I could be wrong but it looks like `search(Origin_Zip, stop=stop, pause=5.0)`  doesn't always return a list (but an int).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!   I am not fluent with lambda functions, thus, not certain if, 'search(Origin_Zip, stop=stop, pause=5.0)' returns an int vs a list.    Also, my ability to deconstruct (i.e. convert to a function) that lambda function is limited.  Any suggestions specifics steps to this process?

Comment: rather than use `lambda x: ...`, use `def f(x): ...` (over several lines) and then call `.apply(f)`. What did you think `search(Origin_Zip, stop=stop, pause=5.0)` did?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to diagnose the problem just by looking at the traceback. Working backwards from where the exception was raised:

```
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\urllib.pyc in quote_plus(s, safe)
   1290 def quote_plus(s, safe=''):
   1291     """Quote the query fragment of a URL; replacing ' ' with '+'"""
-> 1292     if ' ' in s:
   1293         s = quote(s, safe + ' ')
   1294         return s.replace(' ', '+')

TypeError: argument of type 'numpy.int64' is not iterable
```

This tells me that `s` is a `numpy.int64` rather than a string. `s` is the `query` input to `quote_plus(query)`:

```
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\google.pyc in search(query, tld, lang, num, start, stop, pause, only_standard)
    174 
    175     # Prepare the search string.
--> 176     query = quote_plus(query)
    177 
    178     # Grab the cookie from the home page.
```

From looking at the part after "`in`", which shows where these lines were executed, I can tell that `query` is the first argument to the `google.search()` function:

```
search(query, tld, lang, num, start, stop, pause, only_standard)
```

Without even looking at the documentation, I can therefore infer from the traceback that `search` expects its first argument to be a string, but it is currently getting a `numpy.int64`.

The input to `google.search()` is generated by this nasty-looking `lambda` function:

```
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\lib.pyd in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:56997)()

<ipython-input-4-1a75d4fe26fb> in <lambda>(Origin_Zip)
     34 # First, apply() to call the google distance Matrix for each 'row'
     35 # A list is built for the urls return by search()
---> 36 df[urlcols] = df['Origin_Zip'].apply(lambda Origin_Zip : pd.Series([destinations for destinations in search(Origin_Zip, stop=stop, pause=5.0)][:stop]))
     37 
     38
```

The relevant part is `search(Origin_Zip, stop=stop, pause=5.0)`. Each `Origin_Zip` here will be a value taken from the `'Origin_Zip'` column of `df`, which pinpoints the source of the problem: `df['Origin_Zip']` should contain strings, but at the moment it contains `numpy.int64`s.

Based on your screenshot, I'm guessing that since the string values in the CSV file look like `'90278'`, pandas is automatically converting them to integer values. If you convert that column to strings then the problem will probably go away, for example:

```
df['Origin_Zip'] = df['Origin_Zip'].astype(str)
```